# Defaulting locale if locale missing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, locale

I have my web app translated into english and croatian. English being set as default locale in my config/application.rb and enabled all fallbacks:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
I18n.enforce_available_locales = true
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]
config.i18n.fallbacks = {'es' => 'en', 'fr' => 'en', 'de' => 'en'}
```

My config/routes.rb are defined like this:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|hr/ do
  root :to => 'static_pages#home'
  match 'signin', to: 'sessions#new', via: 'get'
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
  match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

end
```

Everything works perfect when a user is using the app and switches between the languages, but if a user goes to the url and types in for example "es" instead of "en" or "hr" I get a routing error page with the error description: No route matches [GET] "/es/signin"

How can I make it fallback to english locale, if the whole .yml file in the locales folder is missing?

Comment: Maybe it's because of you specified exact values for locale parameter (`:locale => /en|hr/`)?

Comment: I have to have those values defined like that (since I only have those two). If I remove them the whole app isn't working.

Comment: If you prefix path with anything except `en` or `hr` it will cause routing error. What will be the output if you add `es` to regex? `:locale => /en|hr|es/`?

Comment: It works then! I get a flash message that I created.

Comment: Great, I'll post the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `es` or any other locale to your regex in config/routes.rb: `:locale => /en|hr|es/`. Anything except those values will cause routing error.

Comment: This is an ok solution if the user is only going to type in 'es'. But if he types anything else the error page will be shown again.I'd like to find a way to avoid that.

Comment: It's ok to see routing error in development and 404 in production if user types manually `/asdasdasdasd/signin`. I suggest to list expected locales and forget about unexpected behaviour.